# How to update child value in firebase when itemview of recyclerview comes within screen area?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to update child value when user will reach the each itemview of recyclerview

Suppose i have "Users" node in firebase database. and it has three child named "Title" , "Description" and "count" like this

```
{
Users:
 "UID":
    "Title":"..."
    "Description":"..."
    "count":"..."
{
```

And to get value of this child i implements the code

```
@Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, Model model) {
                holder.setTxtTitle(model.getmTitle());
                holder.setTxtDesc(model.getmDesc());

                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Now i want to update "count" value ONLY WHEN itemview is comes within screen.
Suppose i have 5 UID node in Users node so i will get 5 itemview.
when users load these all 5 uid

if user CURRENTLY seeing  1 itemview than update only it child "count" value.
if user CURRENTLY seeing  2 itemview than update only it child "count" value.

In short "Count" value only change when itemview will come in screen on scrolling

Comment: I am not sure excatly what you want but I guess that there is a list of UID and each UID is an item of RecyclerView. Now I have a question, whether you want to update the count value for each item on screen visibility or after use user interaction such as click event or like so? If on screen visibility then whether the UID's count value will update each time when scroll will bring the item in the screen visibilty area by scroll up and down?

Comment: yes its exactly what i ask for

Comment: I want to update the count value for each item on screen visibility

Comment: @Hari N Jha please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to represent the logic but I couldn't get chance to run it. I have tried to write on notepad++ editor so no sure if syntax error will show on AndroidStudio but you the logic will be similar to this.

```
private RecyclerView list;

private adapter recyclerAdapter;

private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

private int visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, firstVisibleItemPosition, lastVisibleItem;
private int oldFirstVisibleItemPos = -1, oldLastVisibleItemPos = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view5);
    recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerAdapter = new adapter(RecyclerViewActivity5.this, country);
    recView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

    firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    updateVisibleItem();
}

private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItemPosition +visibleItemCount;
        Toast.makeText(RecyclerViewActivity5.this, "Visible Item Total:"+String.valueOf(visibleItemCount), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        updateVisibleItem();
    }
};

private void updateVisibleItem() {
    if(oldFirstVisibleItemPos == -1 && lastVisibleItem == -1) {
        oldFirstVisibleItemPos = firstVisibleItemPosition;
        oldLastVisibleItemPos = lastVisibleItem;
    } else if(firstVisibleItemPosition < oldFirstVisibleItemPos){

        if(lastVisibleItem < oldFirstVisibleItemPos)
            oldLastVisibleItemPos = lastVisibleItem;
        else
            oldLastVisibleItemPos = oldFirstVisibleItemPos -1;

        oldFirstVisibleItemPos = firstVisibleItemPosition;
    } else {
        if(firstVisibleItemPosition > oldLastVisibleItemPos)
            oldFirstVisibleItemPos = firstVisibleItemPosition;
        else
            oldFirstVisibleItemPos = oldLastVisibleItemPos + 1;
        oldLastVisibleItemPos = lastVisibleItem;
    }

    for(int i = oldFirstVisibleItemPos; i <= oldLastVisibleItemPos; i++) {
        Model model = list.get(i);
        model.setCount(model.getCount() + 1);
    }
}
```

Here, list is your Model list view and each model will have count as a variable. The method updateVisibleItem() is used to update the item wise count by eliminating overlapped screen visible item.

I hope that this will help you to get you requirement done.